# Gloox library receiving blank messages from Google Hangouts

Tags: xmpp, instant-messaging, google-hangouts, gloox

I'm having a difficult problem with Google Hangouts and my XMPP client which uses the Gloox library, where the former is literally sending blank messages to the latter. Here is an excerpt from the raw log files:

```
<mId>66</mId>
<timestamp>2016-Mar-13 03:45:58</timestamp>
<area>131072</area>
<level>0</level>
<message>
<message from='##################@public.talk.google.com' to='#########@gmail.com' type='chat' id='62859D13'><nos:x value='disabled' xmlns:nos='google:nosave'/><arc:record otr='false' xmlns:arc='http://jabber.org/protocol/archive'/></message>
</message>
```

I found a potential lead at [ 1 ] but I can't quite pinpoint the exact reason between that and why there are blank messages. I just know there is a link between those two.

[ 1 ] - https://developers.google.com/talk/jep_extensions/otr#null

If anyone with XMPP experience could chip in then this would be GREATLY appreciated, as I've done countless hours of debugging which has only ended in futility.